# dynamic role and permission in vue

Tags: laravel, vue.js, routes

guys, I m new to Vue and don't know how I can do that let start my explanation suppose I have 2 users, 1-admin 2-user and I have  sidebar menu like 1.profile 2.purchase 3.add new role 4.setting now when  admin  login he should able to see all link and admin assign permission to user like he is able to see profile, purchase or all link according to role assigned by admin sidebar should be visible to user for eg :- if admin assign user to see purchase then after user login sidebar has only purchase and other should be disable is this possible in vue or any ideas to achieve this

Comment: It's possible with vue.js, but I think you should do it both on the server side and in client side. If you do it just with vue.js, the user may not be able to see the links, but he still can access them.

Comment: @Neos07 I had done with the server but don't know how to do on client side  .provide example

Comment: Check my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible with vue.js, but I think you should do it both on the server side and in client side. If you do it just with vue.js, the user may not be able to see the links, but he still can access them.

If you just want to hide the sidebar elements, you will use:
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html

Something like this:

```
<div id="app">
<div id="profile" v-if="role == 'admin' || (role == 'user' && user_permissions.profile)">
<div id="purchase" v-if="role == 'admin' || (role == 'user' && user_permissions.purchase)">
</div>

<script>
var app = new Vue(
{
  el: '#app',
  data: 
  {
    role: 'user', // or role: 'admin'
    user_permissions:
    {
        profile: false,
        purchase: true,
        add: false,
        role: false,
        setting: false
    }
  }
})
```

The user_permissions object holds what the user role can and cannot access.